# How to Calculate the Percentage Contribution Within Rows in a Data Frame in R

Tags: r, dataframe

I wanted to know, if we can calculate the percentage contribution of the values within a row in a data frame.

The data frame I am working with is:

```
structure(list(`Row Labels` = c("X1", "X2", "X3", "X4"), `2019-01-01` = c(37, 
36, 45, 53), `2019-02-01` = c(3, 19, 14, 46), `2019-03-01` = c(28, 
2, 28, 28), `2019-04-01` = c(48, 70, 18, 16), `2019-05-01` = c(83, 
71, 58, 26), `2019-06-01` = c(85, 28, 83, 46), `2019-07-01` = c(60, 
20, 12, 77), `2019-08-01` = c(44, 66, 30, 99), `2019-09-01` = c(21, 
14, 31, 21), `2019-10-01` = c(26, 72, 72, 16), `2019-11-01` = c(15, 
96, 23, 100), `2019-12-01` = c(65, 0, 98, 66)), row.names = c(NA, 
-4L), class = c("tbl_df", "tbl", "data.frame"))
```

The code which I wrote for this is given below:

```
Book1 <- read_excel("X:/X/X/X - X/X/Book1.xlsx")

First_Date <- "2019-01-01"
Last_Date <- "2019-12-01"

Book1 <- Book1 %>% 
  mutate(Sum = rowSums(pick(any_of(First_Date):any_of(Last_Date)))) %>% 
  mutate(across(pick(any_of(First_Date):any_of(Last_Date), ~./rowSums(pick(any_of(First_Date):any_of(Last_Date)))),.names = "{.col}_%"))
```

When I am running this code, the error I get is:

```
Error in `mutate()`: ℹ In argument: `across(...)`. Caused by error in `pick()`: ! Formula shorthand must be wrapped in `where()`.

  # Bad   data %>% select(~./rowSums(pick(any_of(First_Date):any_of(Last_Date))))

  # Good   data %>% select(where(~./rowSums(pick(any_of(First_Date):any_of(Last_Date)))))
```

The code above should get the output of the below image

[image]

but I dont mind if the output is in this format as well

[image]

Can someone let me know what is it that i am getting wrong to find the contribution? It would be helpful. Is there a simpler way of doing it?

Comment: Generally, it's unusual to need both `across()` and `pick()` in one line - use one or the other.  `across()` if you're doing column-wise operations, `pick()` if you need to work on a subset dataframe as a whole.

Comment: @PaulStaffordAllen Thank you. I used any of thinking that it would help return the index numbers and thought across would be used for those columns based on the index.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For the second output with `dplyr` you can:

```
library(dplyr)

df %>% 
  rowwise() %>% 
  mutate(across(where(is.numeric), ~ .x / sum(across(where(is.numeric)))))

# A tibble: 4 × 13
# Rowwise: 
  `Row Labels` `2019-01-01` `2019-02-01` `2019-03-01` `2019-04-01` `2019-05-01` `2019-06-01` `2019-07-01` `2019-08-01` `2019-09-01` `2019-10-01` `2019-11-01`
  <chr>               <dbl>        <dbl>        <dbl>        <dbl>        <dbl>        <dbl>        <dbl>        <dbl>        <dbl>        <dbl>        <dbl>
1 X1                 0.0718      0.00583      0.0544        0.0932       0.161        0.165        0.117        0.0854       0.0408       0.0505       0.0291
2 X2                 0.0729      0.0385       0.00405       0.142        0.144        0.0567       0.0405       0.134        0.0283       0.146        0.194 
3 X3                 0.0879      0.0273       0.0547        0.0352       0.113        0.162        0.0234       0.0586       0.0605       0.141        0.0449
4 X4                 0.0892      0.0774       0.0471        0.0269       0.0438       0.0774       0.130        0.167        0.0354       0.0269       0.168 
# ℹ 1 more variable: `2019-12-01` <dbl>
```

Multiply with 100:

```
df %>%
  rowwise() %>%
  mutate(across(
    where(is.numeric), ~ .x / sum(across(where(is.numeric))) * 100
                ))
```

Comment: What does `rowwise()` do in R? Is it similar to `group_by()` but for rows?

Comment: @MrPool You could say that say - in this case you can actually replace rowwise() with group_by(). But be careful if there mutiple instances of X1 for example

Comment: Thank you for the help. Just a small question, if I have to multiply this with 100 to get the percentage. Do we put the 100 between `across()` function?
Also is there a way we can specify the column instead of using `is.numeric` while using `across()`?

Comment: @MrPool Inside `across`, please see my edit! :)

Comment: Thank you so much. One more question is there a way to specific the column rather than using `is.numeric`

Comment: @MrPool how specific do you want it to be exactly? Feel free to edit you question to reflect this issue :)